# How to merge 2 stacked column chart?

Tags: powerbi

**Description**

Currently, I have 2 stacked column charts:

*1. Number of people by country.*

I use a stacked column chart to see the number of men and the number of women by country.

*2. Number of pets by country.*

I use a stacked column chart to see different groups (dogs / cats / other) by country.

**Objective**

My objective is to merge both to have only one graph.

For example, on Left Vertical axis, the number of people and on the Right Vertical axis, the number of pets.

Both (number of people, the number of pets) have to use the same X axis.

Is it possible to do this with PowerBI ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a perfect solution to this.

One option would be to take a look at custom visuals like this one:

[Clustered Stacked Bar Chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa200001934)

With the built-in bar charts, you can do something similar if you shape your data right.

For example, if you shape your data like this:

[image: Data]

then you can place Country and Type both on the x-axis and drill down to get a visual like this:

[image: Visual]

There aren't two vertical axes but it's not too far off.